# Addition of columns after doing arithmetic operations in pyspark

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am actually new to pyspark and i am trying to do some data manipulations with it.
I have a DataFrame like below example:

```
Trxn Cust_ID Group
3370    A     1
8809    C     2
3525    B     3
8260    A     3
6349    B     3
3359    C     3
3701    NULL  3
5572    NULL  2
2580    A     1
```

In this DF, Trxn's are unique and the `cust_id`'s can be repetitive and every `cust_id` belongs to some group. I need a Final Dataframe with the new group column names like `array(Group_1, Group_2.. so on)` where I do have a count of `cust_id`'s belong to each group. Below is the output example:

```
Trxn Cust_ID Group  Group_1 Group_2 Group_3
3370   A       1      2       0       1
8809   C       2      0       1       1
3525   B       3      0       0       2
8260   A       3      2       0       1
6349   B       3      0       0       2
3359   C       3      0       1       1
3701   NULL    3      0       1       1
5572   NULL    2      0       1       1
2580   A       1      2       0       1
```

Can someone let me know how to get this exact output in pyspark? Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to do pivot here.
https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html